# How to strip html tags classes and ids and preserve only form and it's elements with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, strip-tags

I have been looking around to find something that would allow me to reliably strip a chunk of HTML code down to a bare form and its elements. I need a solution to remove all non form elements including all content, classes and ids. I am okay using JavaScript or PHP.

Can someone point me in the right direction and/or provide some minor sample code and advice to get me started?

To give you some context..

In most cases autoresponder service providers offer various types of embed-able code. For reasons I will never understand they NEVER offer a CLEAN form code.. there is always some ugly junk around that then has to be cleaned up..

Here is an example embedable code from a responder service

```
<style>
  ._form {
  position:relative;
  background:#fff;
  width:400px;/*F*/
  padding:0!important;
  text-align:left;
  }
  ._form em {
  color:#9a9a9a;
  }
  ._form a {
  margin-left:3px;
  }
  ._form ._field,
  ._form ._field ._label,
  ._form ._type_radio,
  ._form ._type_checkbox,
  ._form ._type_captcha,
  ._form ._field table {
  background:none;
  }
  ._form ._field  {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  cursor:move;
  font-style:normal;
  margin:1.2em 0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
  ._form ._field input[type="text"] {
  width:100%;
  padding:8px;
  font-size:16px;
  border:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ._form ._field ._label {
  display:block;
  margin:0 0 0.5em;
  padding:0!important;
  font-size:15px;
  }
  ._form ._field ._option input[type="checkbox"],
  ._form ._field ._option input[type="radio"] {
  position:relative;
  width:13px;
  height:13px;
  margin:-4px 0 0 1px;
  cursor:pointer;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
  ._form ._field ._option input[type="submit"],
  ._form ._field ._option input[type="button"] {
  margin:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  height:35px;
  width:auto;
  font-size:15px;
  }
  ._form ._field ._option select {
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:auto;
  font-size:15px;
  border:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  }
  ._form ._type_radio ._option,
  ._form ._type_checkbox ._option {
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:normal;
  line-height:1.8;
  }
  ._form ._type_date ._option input[type="text"] {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ._form ._type_date ._option input[type="button"] {
  width:37px;
  height:36px;
  margin-left:5px;
  padding:20px;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  }
  ._form ._type_captcha img {
  float:left;
  margin:0 6px 0 0;
  width:70px;
  height:33px;
  border:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  }
  ._form ._type_captcha input[type="text"] {
  margin:-14px 0 0 0!important;
  width:25%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ._form ._field table  {
  width:100%!important;
  }
  ._form ._field table tbody tr td  {
  width:50%!important;
  font-size:15px;
  }
  ._form {
  width:265px;/*F*/
  background:#fff;
  color:#2c2c2c;
  font-weight:normal;
  }
  ._form #notice {
  margin:10px 0 0 -3px!important;
  padding:0;
  color:#acacac;
  font-size:11px;
  font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
  }
  ._form #notice a:link, ._form #notice a:visited {
  color:#acacac;
  text-decoration:underline;
  }
  ._form ._field  {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  cursor:default;
  font-style:normal;
  margin:0 0 16px;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
  ._form ._field input[type="text"],
  ._form ._field input[type="email"] {
  width:100%;
  padding:4px;
  font-size:14px;
  background:#fafafa;
  border:1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-top:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ._form ._field ._label {
  margin:0 0 4px;
  color:#2c2c2c;
  font-size:13px;
  font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  }
  ._form ._field ._option {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  color:#2c2c2c;
  font-size:13px;
  font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight:normal;
  line-height:20px;
  }
  ._form ._type_header ._label {
  width:100%;
  font-style:normal;
  font-size:16px!important;
  line-height:20px;
  color:#005698;
  margin:0 0 5px!important;
  padding:0 0 10px!important;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
  }
  ._form ._type_input ._option  textarea{
  width:97%!important;
  background:#fafafa;
  border:1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-top:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  border-radius:3px;
  }
  ._form ._type_input ._option input[type="submit"],
  ._form ._type_input ._option input[type="button"] {
  width:auto;
  margin:10px 0 0!important;
  padding:2px 15px!important;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-family:verdana,arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:12px;
  color:#3f3f3f;
  background:#f7f7f7;
  border:1px solid #999999;
  border-bottom:1px solid #888888;
  text-align:center;
  }
  ._form ._type_input ._option input[type="submit"]:hover,
  ._form ._type_input ._option input[type="button"]:hover {
  border:1px solid #afafaf;
  border-bottom:1px solid #a5a5a5;
  background:#f7f7f7;
  color:#525252;
  }
  ._form ._type_date ._option input[type="text"] {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  }
  ._form ._type_radio ._option label {
  display:inline;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;
  line-height:18px;
  }
  ._form ._type_radio ._option label input[type="radio"] {
  position:relative;
  width:13px;
  height:13px;
  margin:-4px 0 0 1px;
  cursor:pointer;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:20px;
  }
  ._form ._type_date ._option input[type="button"] {
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  margin:2px 0 0 5px;
  padding:0;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  }
  ._form ._field ._option select {
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:auto;
  font-size:14px;
  border:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  }
  ._form ._type_captcha img {
  float:left;
  width:42px;
  height:24px;
  margin:0 6px 0 0;
  border:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  }
  ._form ._type_captcha input[type="text"] {
  float:left;
  margin:0!important;
  width:40%;
  font-size:14px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ._form ._field table {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%!important;
  table-layout:fixed;
  margin-bottom:18px;
  font-size:13px!important;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
  }
  ._form ._field table td {
  padding:0 10px 0 0!important;
  line-height:18px;
  text-align:left;
  font-size:13px!important;
  color:#606060;
  }
  ._form ._type_input ._option  table tbody#_forward_rcpt input {margin:0 0 4px 0; width:96%!important;}
  ._form ._type_input ._option  table tbody#_forward_rcpt img.image_addrcpt {cursor:pointer;}
  .form_errors{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:15px;
  margin:10px;
  color:#900;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  }
</style>
<form action='//something.com/proc.php' method='post' id='_form_37' accept-charset='utf-8' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input type='hidden' name='f' value='37'>
  <input type='hidden' name='s' value=''>
  <input type='hidden' name='c' value='0'>
  <input type='hidden' name='m' value='0'>
  <input type='hidden' name='act' value='sub'>
  <input type='hidden' name='nlbox[]' value='6'>
  <div class='_form'>
    <div class='formwrapper'>
      <div id='_field284'>
        <div id='compile284' class='_field _type_input'>
          <div class='_label '>
            First Name
          </div>
          <div class='_option'>
            <input type='text' name='field[6]' value=''>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='_field272'>
        <div id='compile272' class='_field _type_input'>
          <div class='_label '>
            Email *
          </div>
          <div class='_option'>
            <input type='email' name='email' >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='_field273'>
        <div id='compile273' class='_field _type_input'>
          <div class='_option'>
            <input type='submit' value="Subscribe">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='_field280'>
        <div id='compile280' class='_field _type_hidden'>
          <div class='_option'>
            <input type='hidden' name='field[4]' value=''>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='_field281'>
        <div id='compile281' class='_field _type_hidden'>
          <div class='_option'>
            <input type='hidden' name='field[5]' value=''>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='_field282'>
        <div id='compile282' class='_field _type_hidden'>
          <div class='_option'>
            <input type='hidden' name='field[3]' value=''>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And this is what I want without having to manually clean it all up:

```
<form action='//something.com/proc.php' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='hidden' name='f' value='37'>
    <input type='hidden' name='s' value=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='c' value='0'>
    <input type='hidden' name='m' value='0'>
    <input type='hidden' name='act' value='sub'>
    <input type='hidden' name='nlbox[]' value='6'>
    First Name
    <input type='text' name='field[6]' value=''>
    Email *
    <input type='email' name='email' >
    <input type='submit' value="Subscribe">
    <input type='hidden' name='field[4]' value=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='field[5]' value=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='field[3]' value=''>
</form>
```

A simple use of strip tags seems to be ok but it doesn't remove css from within  tags

I added example embedable code to string.txt

```
$file = file_get_contents('string.txt', true);
echo '<textarea  rows="50" cols="50">' . $file . '</textarea>';
$file = strip_tags($file, '<form><input>');
echo '<textarea  rows="50" cols="80">' . $file . '</textarea>';
```

And finally I made some progress with this but it is imperfect,,, the ID is still on form element and I foresee more issues

```
$file = file_get_contents('string.txt', true);

function strip_html_tags( $text )
{
$text = preg_replace(
    array(
        // Remove invisible content
        '@<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>@siu',
        '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siu',
        '@<script[^>]*?.*?</script>@siu',
        '@<object[^>]*?.*?</object>@siu',
        '@<embed[^>]*?.*?</embed>@siu',
        '@<applet[^>]*?.*?</applet>@siu',
        '@<noframes[^>]*?.*?</noframes>@siu',
        '@<noscript[^>]*?.*?</noscript>@siu',
        '@<noembed[^>]*?.*?</noembed>@siu',
    ),
    array(
        ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',
        "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0", "\n\$0",
        "\n\$0", "\n\$0",
    ),
    $text );

return strip_tags( $text, '<form><input>' );
}

$newText = strip_html_tags($file);

echo '<textarea  rows="50" cols="80">' . $newText . '</textarea>';
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yet? For tags use `strip_tags`, as for the others maybe look in to regex.

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more context? There are multiple ways to do this depending on what the actual use is.

jQuery is good for client side, and PHP str_replace or preg_replace is good for server site... really depends on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I added some context above,, and for those that are quick to down vote and point to "duplicate questions" it would be far more useful if you actually showed some constraint, communicated with the asker and tried to actually understand what is asked rather then display arrogance and impatience. There is no way you could have known what I am actually asking within less then 60 seconds of asking.

Comment: I looked at strip_tags() .. I am working on something with it right now.. but I don't feel happy about it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the output like

```
<form action="//something.com/proc.php" method="post" id="_form_37" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="f" value="37"><input type="hidden" name="s" value=""><input type="hidden" name="c" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="m" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="act" value="sub"><input type="hidden" name="nlbox[]" value="6">

            First Name

            <input type="text" name="field[6]" value="">

            Email *

            <input type="email" name="email">

            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">

            <input type="hidden" name="field[4]" value="">

            <input type="hidden" name="field[5]" value="">

            <input type="hidden" name="field[3]" value="">

</form>
```

If that is right I think this would do it:

```
$string = '<style>
  ._form {
  position:relative;
  background:#fff;
  width:400px;/*F*/
  padding:0!important;
  text-align:left;
  }
  ._form em {
  color:#9a9a9a;
  }
  ._form a {
  margin-left:3px;
  }
  ._form ._field,
  ._form ._field ._label,
  ._form ._type_radio,
  ._form ._type_checkbox,
  ._form ._type_captcha,
  ._form ._field table {
  background:none;
  }
  ._form ._field  {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  cursor:move;
  font-style:normal;
  margin:1.2em 0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
  ._form ._field input[type="text"] {
  width:100%;
  padding:8px;
  font-size:16px;
  border:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ._form ._field ._label {
  display:block;
  margin:0 0 0.5em;
  padding:0!important;
  font-size:15px;
  }
  ._form ._field ._option input[type="checkbox"],
  ._form ._field ._option input[type="radio"] {
  position:relative;
  width:13px;
  height:13px;
  margin:-4px 0 0 1px;
  cursor:pointer;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
  ._form ._field ._option input[type="submit"],
  ._form ._field ._option input[type="button"] {
  margin:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  height:35px;
  width:auto;
  font-size:15px;
  }
  ._form ._field ._option select {
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:auto;
  font-size:15px;
  border:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  }
  ._form ._type_radio ._option,
  ._form ._type_checkbox ._option {
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:normal;
  line-height:1.8;
  }
  ._form ._type_date ._option input[type="text"] {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ._form ._type_date ._option input[type="button"] {
  width:37px;
  height:36px;
  margin-left:5px;
  padding:20px;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  }
  ._form ._type_captcha img {
  float:left;
  margin:0 6px 0 0;
  width:70px;
  height:33px;
  border:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  }
  ._form ._type_captcha input[type="text"] {
  margin:-14px 0 0 0!important;
  width:25%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ._form ._field table  {
  width:100%!important;
  }
  ._form ._field table tbody tr td  {
  width:50%!important;
  font-size:15px;
  }
  ._form {
  width:265px;/*F*/
  background:#fff;
  color:#2c2c2c;
  font-weight:normal;
  }
  ._form #notice {
  margin:10px 0 0 -3px!important;
  padding:0;
  color:#acacac;
  font-size:11px;
  font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
  }
  ._form #notice a:link, ._form #notice a:visited {
  color:#acacac;
  text-decoration:underline;
  }
  ._form ._field  {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  cursor:default;
  font-style:normal;
  margin:0 0 16px;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
  ._form ._field input[type="text"],
  ._form ._field input[type="email"] {
  width:100%;
  padding:4px;
  font-size:14px;
  background:#fafafa;
  border:1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-top:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ._form ._field ._label {
  margin:0 0 4px;
  color:#2c2c2c;
  font-size:13px;
  font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  }
  ._form ._field ._option {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  color:#2c2c2c;
  font-size:13px;
  font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight:normal;
  line-height:20px;
  }
  ._form ._type_header ._label {
  width:100%;
  font-style:normal;
  font-size:16px!important;
  line-height:20px;
  color:#005698;
  margin:0 0 5px!important;
  padding:0 0 10px!important;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
  }
  ._form ._type_input ._option  textarea{
  width:97%!important;
  background:#fafafa;
  border:1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-top:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  border-radius:3px;
  }
  ._form ._type_input ._option input[type="submit"],
  ._form ._type_input ._option input[type="button"] {
  width:auto;
  margin:10px 0 0!important;
  padding:2px 15px!important;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-family:verdana,arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:12px;
  color:#3f3f3f;
  background:#f7f7f7;
  border:1px solid #999999;
  border-bottom:1px solid #888888;
  text-align:center;
  }
  ._form ._type_input ._option input[type="submit"]:hover,
  ._form ._type_input ._option input[type="button"]:hover {
  border:1px solid #afafaf;
  border-bottom:1px solid #a5a5a5;
  background:#f7f7f7;
  color:#525252;
  }
  ._form ._type_date ._option input[type="text"] {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  }
  ._form ._type_radio ._option label {
  display:inline;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;
  line-height:18px;
  }
  ._form ._type_radio ._option label input[type="radio"] {
  position:relative;
  width:13px;
  height:13px;
  margin:-4px 0 0 1px;
  cursor:pointer;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:20px;
  }
  ._form ._type_date ._option input[type="button"] {
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  margin:2px 0 0 5px;
  padding:0;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  }
  ._form ._field ._option select {
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:auto;
  font-size:14px;
  border:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  }
  ._form ._type_captcha img {
  float:left;
  width:42px;
  height:24px;
  margin:0 6px 0 0;
  border:1px solid #b6b6b6;
  }
  ._form ._type_captcha input[type="text"] {
  float:left;
  margin:0!important;
  width:40%;
  font-size:14px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ._form ._field table {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%!important;
  table-layout:fixed;
  margin-bottom:18px;
  font-size:13px!important;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
  }
  ._form ._field table td {
  padding:0 10px 0 0!important;
  line-height:18px;
  text-align:left;
  font-size:13px!important;
  color:#606060;
  }
  ._form ._type_input ._option  table tbody#_forward_rcpt input {margin:0 0 4px 0; width:96%!important;}
  ._form ._type_input ._option  table tbody#_forward_rcpt img.image_addrcpt {cursor:pointer;}
  .form_errors{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:15px;
  margin:10px;
  color:#900;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  }
</style>
<form action="//something.com/proc.php" method="post" id="_form_37" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="f" value="37">
  <input type="hidden" name="s" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="c" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="m" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="act" value="sub">
  <input type="hidden" name="nlbox[]" value="6">
  <div class="_form">
    <div class="formwrapper">
      <div id="_field284">
        <div id="compile284" class="_field _type_input">
          <div class="_label ">
            First Name
          </div>
          <div class="_option">
            <input type="text" name="field[6]" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="_field272">
        <div id="compile272" class="_field _type_input">
          <div class="_label ">
            Email *
          </div>
          <div class="_option">
            <input type="email" name="email" >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="_field273">
        <div id="compile273" class="_field _type_input">
          <div class="_option">
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="_field280">
        <div id="compile280" class="_field _type_hidden">
          <div class="_option">
            <input type="hidden" name="field[4]" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="_field281">
        <div id="compile281" class="_field _type_hidden">
          <div class="_option">
            <input type="hidden" name="field[5]" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="_field282">
        <div id="compile282" class="_field _type_hidden">
          <div class="_option">
            <input type="hidden" name="field[3]" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($string);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$forms = $doc->getElementsByTagName('form');
foreach($forms as $form) {
    echo preg_replace('~^\s+$~m', "", strip_tags($doc->saveHTML($form), '<form><input>'));
}
```

It is best to avoid regexing HTML/XML unless there is a consistent pattern (and even then usually better to avoid).

**Update:**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($string);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$forms = $doc->getElementsByTagName('form');
foreach($forms as $form) {
    $form->removeAttribute('id');
    $form->removeAttribute('class');
    foreach($form->getElementsByTagName('input') as $input) {
        $input->removeAttribute('class');
        $input->removeAttribute('id');
    }
    echo preg_replace('~^\s+$~m', "", strip_tags($doc->saveHTML($form), '<form><input>'));
}
```

Comment: I see. This looks promising. Do you think this be extended to remove ids and classes from elements and do some formatting?

Comment: You can use the `removeAttribute` function, added example.

Comment: Note that `DOMDocument`'s `loadHTML()` method does quite respect whitespace in the original HTML code.

Comment: This was of great help. Thank you! :) I found more samples and good info on this approach thanks to you @chris85